# How to construct Dockerfile with 2 files and commands?

Tags: docker, python, containers, image

My app has two files: 1.py and 2.py, and to work i need to run them on two different terminals , like this:

1 terminal: python3 1.py -f text.txt

2 terminal: python3 2.py

How i need to construct my Dockerfile, to make the image work?

Answer (score 0):

Docker doesn't have the concept of "terminals".  Your best bet is to run two Docker containers, one for each file, and use Docker Compose or a Kubernetes pod (or an equivalent) to run them both simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile, after you copy your files, you can use a pipe in the CMD, so you can run multiple scripts at the same time. 
Your Dockerfile should look like this (I assume that the files are in your current directory):

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY 1.py /
COPY 2.py /
COPY text.txt /
CMD python3 1.py -f text.txt | python 2.py
```